# What's the best way to implement email open rate monitoring?

Tags: php, email

We need to provide this on our website, so I don't know how much a third party option should be viable. I haven't been able to easily find information about it, because most of the links take you to marketing articles.

One way I am thinking of it is by inserting tracking images into the email body. But what is the common way to ignore the email being opened multiple times on the same day. Have I got to do an individual tracking code for each email sent out?

Comment: exactly that is how I implemented it myself. And that works perfectly.

Comment: With [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com), our messages each have a unique message ID, which we feed into the tracking code to track exactly which email has been opened. That's the standard way to track opens in the email world!

Comment: If this is the only means, than I assume I have to include that identifier in the links that point to our website, just in case the users email client blocked the images...

Comment: Not sure if you mean click tracking or open tracking. But yes, in either case you'd have to include the identifier in both the tracking image and the links in your emails.

Comment: Open tracking. But I assume the only way to "open track" a user with disabled images is to do an additional check when he clicks a website link. Don't know how important the difference between users with images displayed, and those that have them disabled is.

Comment: Oh, definitely. That's why open tracking is useful, but you shouldn't rely on it too much - it's inaccurate because of all the clients that block images!

Comment: @mhitza 10 years later I am in your same journey. I want to keep it as simple as possible. What have you learned since this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what statistics you need to collect. If you are looking go gather information on the number of people you sent the email to that opened it, then yes, you need an individual tracking code for each email.

On the other hand, if you are loiking for the number of times an email has been viewed (not the number of people), then a single tracking code will work. Think of the difference as roughly the same as "page views" (or hits) and "unique page views" in many web analytics software packages.